# Grails: how to create a view?

Tags: grails

I am trying to create my first grails app.

```
grails create-app helloworld
cd helloworld
grails
```

With these commands I've created my app. Then I've created my controller with this command

```
grails> create-controller hello
```

At this step I my project folder is like this

[image]

And I can see my project on my localhost:8080 with my hello controller. When I click to my hello controller, I get error.

[image]

I guess it is about the view. There is no view in hello view folder.

I don't understand the problem. Should I create a view, or any other problem  I have about Java?

Comment: Looks like you are learning Grails, Try learning through this free book at http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started and you will be making your own app within few hours getting all the answers for beginners issue like as above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the view GSP yourself in this case. Since you aren't using scaffolding and just have an empty controller.

In your example create the file `grails-app/views/hello/index.gsp`. You can put whatever contents you want in there.